# Multiple mp3 audio not playing in chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I have multiple MP3 audio files loaded in single page using HTML5 Audio tag.

I can able to load all the players. But i could not play all the players one by one .

In random manner some audio files are not played in chrome browser and its working fine in FF and IE browser.

I don't know whether it is the cache issue  or any other browser or RAM issue. So kindly help me**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken, I am loading 70 audio files in my page and using preload="metadata". But loading is not a issue and also i didn't click players simultaneously. i am just playing audio one by one (one finished then click other one for play). sometimes it can able to play upto 20 and sometimes 30 after that some intermediate players gets struck and after some audio plays well

Comment: Chrome#49 has some issues related to audio/video TAGs (only one of these TAGs are allowed and must be reused).

Answer (score 1):

How many are you loading, and what have you set the `preload` attribute to? Chrome has a limit of about 6 that it allows to load at the same time.

You could set 6 of them to have `preload="metadata"` or `preload="auto"` and all the others to have `preload="none"` (this means that they will only load when the user clicks play).

Comment: Ian, i am loading 70 audio files in my page and using preload="metadata". But loading is not a issue and also i didn't click players simultaneously. i am just playing audio one by one (one finished then click other one for play). sometimes it can able to play upto 20 and sometimes 30 after that some intermediate players gets struck and after some audio plays well..

Comment: Ah ok, my apologies, I appear to have misunderstood.